# Trying to access a Variable that is in a list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I'm attempting to access specific values in the following dictionary (dictionary's name is CourseDictionary)

```
{'Math': [4.0, 4.0, 'A'], 'Science': [3.0, 3.0, 'B']}
```

I need to make a `function` that multiplies the first and second values of each of the lists inside this **dictionary** but I'm not sure exactly how to access the specific variables I need.
I tried doing a few things but the things I was trying didn't work since the `function` needs to be called inside of a loop since the number of entry's in the dictionary can be any number.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {k: v[0] * v[1] for k, v in CourseDictionary.items()}
```

This would make a dictionary of `subject: product of values` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
def multiply():
     CourseDictionary['Math'][0] = CourseDictionary['Math'] [0]*CourseDictionary['Math'][1]
     CourseDictionary['Math'].pop(1)
     CourseDictionary['Science'][0] = CourseDictionary['Science'] [0]*CourseDictionary['Science'][1]
     CourseDictionary['Science'].pop(1)
```

This basically multiplies the first two items and puts them in the 1st space, then deletes the second item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean dictionary as in python library? As in it has values that you want?
You probably want to try this:

```
Import CourseDictionary as dict
#Make sure that the CourseDictionary is in the same directory as your program
```

Then you can access the variables by name and extract the information that you need.